# Error TF31004 when connecting to TFS2008

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I'm trying to connect to a TFS2008 server through Visual Studio 2008 (Tools\Connect to Team Foundation Server) and get this error when trying to add our server:

> TF31004: Team Foundation encountered an unexpected error while connecting to Team Foundation Server . Wait a few minutes and try again. If the problem persists, contact your Team Foundation Server administrator.

Needless to say, waiting doesn't help. I've tried using the ip address instead of the hostname but get the same error.

I *can* log in via a browser, in fact IE and Chrome both SSO me straight in.

The server is only used for testing one of our TFS plugins, so doesn't get much real use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I discovered the problem, will document it here for anyone else.

It turned out I wasn't in the TFS 'Licensed Users' AD group. I found this out by trying to connect to TFS from VS2008 installed on the server, which gave me an accurate error message.

Answer (score 0):

Another reason for this error is that the proxy has been set to a proxy that cannot access the TFS server.

**Steps to fix:**

1. Open "Internet Options" ( Windows-R inetcpl.cpl )
2. Click the "Connections" tab
3. Click the "LAN Settings" button
4. Either uncheck the "Use proxy server...." or put in a proxy that can connect to your TFS server.